# How to add the result of multiple queries in influxdb / grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

Actually I want the cardinality of the tag value in the influxdb database with multiple measurements.
e.g. DB has m1,m2,m3 measurements and I wrote the query as
**show tag values cardinality on Db from m1 with key = "key"**
this query return the result suppose 6. Now I want to add this result with the result of the other query **show tag values cardinality on Db from m2 with key = "key"**
and it also returns some number.
I want to add these numbers and display them in the grafana dashboard. But I can't figure out how to add the results of these queries.